# Cloudinary Image Upload errpr in django python while hosted in pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, cloudinary, pythonanywhere

So i use pythonanywhere to host a django website where pictures are uploaded and shown the uploaded pictures are stored in cloudinary showing the pictures is working fine but when i upload a post i get this error:

```
Error at /post/
Unexpected error - MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.cloudinary.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1_1/meme-topia/image/upload (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f8d77f41370>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))")
```

Models file:

```
from django.db import models
from cloudinary.models import CloudinaryField


# Create your models here.
class MemeImg(models.Model):
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Post_Img = CloudinaryField('image')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Title
```

Forms file:

```
from django import forms
from .models import MemeImg


class PostImg(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MemeImg
        fields = '__all__'
```

And then the source code link:https://github.com/Shadow-Knight503/memoster503.git

Please help

Comment: Note that you shouldn't publicly expose your API_SECRET as mentioned here: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/cloudinary_glossary#api_key_and_secret. 
I would recommend resetting your pair on [your dashboard](https://cloudinary.com/console/settings/security)

Comment: @LoicVdB Thank you but can tell me how to fix my problem please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the keys should be in lower caps. The foolproof way is to go to your Dashboard and download your python settings:

[image]

settings.py should be in this format:

```
CLOUDINARY = {
      'cloud_name': 'CLOUD-NAME',  
      'api_key': 'xx',  
      'api_secret': 'xx',
      'api_proxy': 'http://proxy.server:3128'
}
```

Comment: Glad it worked! Upvote it so others might also benefit ;)

Comment: Sorry i do not have enough reputation to vote

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you have exactly this in your settings.py ?

```
    CLOUDINARY = {
      'CLOUD_NAME': 'CLOUD-NAME',  
      'API_KEY': 'xx',  
      'API_SECRET': 'xx',
      'API_PROXY': 'http://proxy.server:3128'
}
```

Comment: No letme try thanks a lot

Comment: I did it and i am getting this error :
ImproperlyConfigured at /post/
In order to use cloudinary storage, you need to provide CLOUDINARY_STORAGE dictionary with CLOUD_NAME, API_SECRET and API_KEY in the settings or set CLOUDINARY_URL variable (or CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME, CLOUDINARY_API_KEY, CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET variables).

Comment: Please help me ,